# options array in Joomla session?

Tags: session, joomla

I've been analyzing joomla session and I came across a few problems. One of the problems is the session name.

See this code:(seesion.php#894)

```
    protected function _setOptions(array $options)
{
    // Set name
    if (isset($options['name']))
    {
        session_name(md5($options['name']));
    }

    // Set id
    if (isset($options['id']))
    {
        session_id($options['id']);
    }

    // Set expire time
    if (isset($options['expire']))
    {
        $this->_expire = $options['expire'];
    }

    // Get security options
    if (isset($options['security']))
    {
        $this->_security = explode(',', $options['security']);
    }

    if (isset($options['force_ssl']))
    {
        $this->_force_ssl = (bool) $options['force_ssl'];
    }

    // Sync the session maxlifetime
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $this->_expire);

    return true;
}
```

My problem is with the $options array , I add this to the script:

```
print_r($options);
```

the result was: Array ( [name] => 266e79f0eac297f66eaf7926636f03fa [expire] => 900 )

where did this element come from ? I mean is there a value that will allow me to do this:

```
md5('value');
```

and get the same [name] element

Comment: Nope, it's a completely random value or pseudo-random precisely

Comment: You've posted a few times but you haven't really said what you are trying to accomplish so it's really hard to respond.

Comment: I trying to test joomla security I mean if I have the session value and the session name I can make a session of my own and login to the admin panel

Answer (score 0):

Hey i found the answer for this.

The session value is calculated as following.

$hash = md5(md5($secret.'site'));

where $secret is defined in the configuration file.

use following code to get the session value.

include_once(dirname(dirname(**FILE**)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'configuration.php');

$config = new JConfig;
$secret = $config->secret;

$hash = md5(md5($secret.'site'));

So for you the value of name variable comes from md5($secret.'site') which is session value. and if you take md5 again it will give you the session cookie value.